# From numerical pdf to numerical CDF

Tags: r, integration, numerical, cdf

I've estimated a pdf numerically at a set of grid points, and I would like to determine the CDF at this point.

Is there a function to integrate the pdf numerically? Is the function `cumsum()`  enough? When I use `cumsum()` the pdf sums to 1.05 instead of 1.

---

I want to compare two densities over a fine grid using K-L divergence to see if they are the same. I observe the vector Y, which depends on the matrix X (also observed), and I'm interested in g(y), the unconditional distribution of Y. In order to get g(y), I first find the joint density, g(X, Y), and then I divide it by the conditional density g(X | Y). The two densities are determined using the rule-of-thumb method in the np package in R (`npundens`, `npudensbw`, `npcdens`, `npcdensbw`). So, g(y) = g(X, Y) / g(X | Y). However, when I sum the entries in g(y), I get a number larger than 2. Since I want g(y) to be evaluated on a fine grid I compute the kernel regression of g(y) (using npreg with exdat = grid) and save the fitted value from this regression. When I sum them I get a number around than 1.05.

Is this method correct to find the unconditional pdf? Why doesn't the pdf sum to 1?

Method:
    # Compute the joint pdf of Y and X

```
Z <- data.frame(Y, X)
jbw <- npudensbw(dat = Z, bwmethod = 'normal-reference', 
                 xtrim = trim, ytrim = trim)   
jpdf <- npudens(bws = jbw)

# Determine the conditional pdf of the covariates X with respect to the vector Y 

bw <- npcdensbw(xdat = Y, ydat = X, 
               bwmethod = 'normal-reference', xtrim = trim, ytrim = trim)   
cpdf <- npcdens(bws = bw, xdat = Y, ydat = X)

# Determine the unconditional pdf of Y

ft = jpdf$dens / cpdf$condens
print(sum(ft))

# Nonparametric regression of w_ft over Y in order 
to get the extended pdf evaluated in the points in grid

sigma = min(sd(Y, na.rm = TRUE), 
        mad(Y, center = median(Y), constant = 1.4826, 
        na.rm = TRUE, low = FALSE, high = FALSE) / 1.4826, 
        IQR(Y, na.rm = TRUE, type = 7)/1.349)
computed_bw = 1.06 * sigma * length(Y)^(-1.0/(2.0*2+1))

extended_pdf <- fitted(npreg(bws = computed_bw, tydat = ft, txdat = Y, exdat = grid))
```

Comment: Are you using Matlab's `cumsum`? If so you should add the Matlab tag. I think [`cumtrapz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html) would be more appropriate. You can normalize your result so the total probability is 1. Also you might look into producing an [empirical distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) ([`ecdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ecdf.html) in Matlab).

Comment: Hi @horchler. I'm using R. Let me edit the text so that I can give you a better idea of my problem. Thank you!

Comment: The answer as to why you have a relatively minor departure from the expected value of unity can only be addressed by seeing how you derive values submitted to `cumsum`. Numerical integration can be done with a variety of options. You mention nothing about multiplying densities by the associated widths of the grid, and failing to do so could easily give you large errors.You also make no mention of how to deal with the fact that the values at the midpoints of grids may be systematically different than values at either end of an interval, so you may not be using the trapezoidal rule.

Comment: HI @42 I attached my code above. I think I should check the widths of the gird, you are right. But still, I don't understand why I get such a large pdf before I do the kernel regression.

Comment: Your code throws (many) errors. Please clear your workspace and re-run. The dataframe is named either `wZ` or `wz`. Decide which. X and Y are column names and not objects which allow the use of `$`. Define all those undefined values that are throwing errors  or remove unnecessary ones. (Learn to walk before trying to run.)

Comment: @42 Yes, sorry for that. I relabeled the variables when I copied and pasted my code above but apparently I added a few typos. Sorry for that. The code runs fine.

Comment: The last line still throws an error: `Error in toFrame(exdat) : 
  exdat must be a data frame, matrix, vector, or factor`. I don't see any code that defines `grid`. And have you looked at the result from `plot(cpdf)`. I'm thinking bandwidth selection might need some attention.

Comment: I'm thinking bandwidth selection might need some attention. I currently have `X <- rnorm(1000);  Y <- chisq(1000,1,1)`

Comment: I selected the grid to be like this: minimum = min(m_values)
maximum = max(m_values)
grid = (minimum-1):(maximum+1)/1
which is between -54 and 3512

Comment: So you would need to be multiplying your densities (or perhaps an interpolated version) by something like `diff(grid)` allowing for the fact that `diff` always returns length one less than its argument.